# Не отображается компонент в Angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angular

Есть модуль, который выводит свой template. Я хочу в этот template вложить html из компонента.

Модуль:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter, { StateProvider } from '@uirouter/angularjs';
import { CATALOG } from 'common/constants-common/states';
import catalogPageViewComponent from './catalog.component';
import './catalog.less';


export default angular
.module('CatalogPageView', [
    uiRouter
])
.component('catalogPageViewComponent', catalogPageViewComponent)
.config(($stateProvider: StateProvider) => {
    $stateProvider.state(CATALOG, {
        data: {
            state: CATALOG
        },
        url: '/catalog',
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'

    });
})
.name;
```

Компонент который хочу вывести:

```
class CatalogController {
    test = {name: 'Catalog test'};
}

const catalogPageViewComponent = {
    controller: CatalogController,
    template: `<div class="container">{{ $ctrl.test.name }}</div>`
}
export default catalogPageViewComponent;
```

В модуле 'ui-view' - отображается, тут все ок. Не получается отобразить то что в компоненте: 'template: `<div class="container">{{ $ctrl.test.name }}</div>`'

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам. 
Не правильно передавал компонент в модуль.

Подключаю компонет в модуле:
`.component('catalog', catalogPageViewComponent)`

В темплейте модуля указываю:

```
 template: '<catalog></catalog>'
```